# prime faces file upload not working

Tags: javascript, jsf, file-upload, jsf-2, primefaces

Whenever I am using the following javascript in my Home.xhtml page, `<p:fileUpload>` in the page is not working, the CHOOSE,UPLOAD OR CANCEL button , nothing is showing.
Whereas when I am removing the javascript from the page everything is working fine.

1) JavaScript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
/* <![CDATA[ */
    var userName = '<%=request.getParameter("username")%>';
    $(document).ready(function(){ 
        $.cometChat.onLoad({memberListContainerID:'members'});
        join(userName);
    });
    /* ]]> */
</script>
```

Comment: Yre you getting any errors in the error console?

Comment: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'onLoad' of undefined `
I am getting the error in google chrome console

Comment: `$.cometChat` seems not to get loaded then, check where you are loading it

Comment: It looks like a syntax error, Check for the syntax carefully.